# Jackson failing displaying empty array: null inside ([null] )

Tags: java, jackson

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
public String methodName;
public Object[] argument;

public MyClass(String m,Object[]){...
```

I want to send an empty argument array :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyClass cls = new MyClass("list_dbs",new Object[1]);
mapper.writeValue(System.out, req);
```

I get:

> {"methodName":"list_dbs","argument":[null]}

Why is there that "null" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you created your array

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass("list_dbs",new Object[1]);
```

with one element.

So the `Object[]` is

```
[0] = null
```

If you want an empty array, ie. one without elements, you need

```
MyClass cls = new MyClass("list_dbs",new Object[0]);
```